# Trying to create a scrollbar in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to learn Tkinter and create a simple text editor, like notepad, etc.The problem I'm facing is that my scrollbar only works for the first tab of the notebook. All subsequent tabs in the notebook do not have a working scrollbar. The scrollbar appears, but does not work.

Here's the code I'm using to create the actual scrollbar:

```
def create_scroll_bar():
    global text_scroll
    text_scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(scroll, orient="vertical", command=textarea.yview)
    text_scroll.pack(side="right", fill="y")

    textarea["yscrollcommand"] = text_scroll.set

    global scrollbar_count
    scrollbar_count += 1
    print(scrollbar_count)

    if scrollbar_count >= 2:
        text_scroll.destroy()
```

And the code in the entire file, in case it's needed, is in [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/vzJUn8zd).

This is the error I'm getting in my console:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "F:\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3525, in set
    self.tk.call(self._w, 'set', first, last)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!frame2.!frame.!scrollbar2"
```

Image of application running

[image: screenshot of application running]

What am I doing wrong? I think it's because the scrollbar is assigned to the first tab at it's creation, but it needs to be recreated for each new tab, perhaps?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: Why do you destroy just created `text_scroll` if `scrollbar_count >= 2`?

Comment: The code must be included in the question itself, not as a separate paste bin. You have to reduce it to a [mcve] if it's too large to fit in the post.

Comment: You don't need to destroy and create the scrollbar.  Just create one and then update its `command` option and the `yscrollcommand` ot the active `Text` whenever switching tab.

Comment: Every tab should get its own scrollbar.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes, I tried making multiple scrollbars for each tab, but I somehow have to destroy the previous scrollbars as well. Otherwise, we end up with 10 scrollbars on the screen, 1 for each tab.

Comment: @acw1668 As I replied to Bryan, my idea was to create a new scrollbar for each tab, but to delete the previous scrollbar, otherwise the previous scrollbars do not disappear from the screen, and we end up with a messy and broken program.

Comment: You do not need to destroy previous scrollbars. There's nothing preventing you from  having multiple scrollbars, one per notebook tab. Are you trying to have one scrollbar _outside_ of the notebook that controls the contents _inside_ a notebook tab?

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes, that was my initial strategy. But, since the scrollbar was inside the notebook tab, the last (2) characters of the tab were not visible. The scrollbar was in the way. Next, I tried to put the scrollbar outside the notebook tab. Seems I shot myself in the foot there. :)

Comment: @fecigo: it seems impossible for the scrollbar to cut off the tabs if the scrollbar was _inside_ the frame. It can't possibly obscure the text of the tab because it's below the tab.

Comment: @BryanOakley , here's a video showing the issue when putting the scrollbar in the frame: [Video](https://streamable.com/30kjgj).

The problem seems to be in the `create_file()` function and the `create_scroll_bar()` function. This is the code for both functions: [Link](https://pastebin.com/kGnpcLDv).

I can't figure out what's the problem with this.

Comment: You are putting the scrollbar inside the text widget. You shouldn't do that. My answer shows how to put the scrollbar in a frame side-by-side with a text widget.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That solved the issue completely! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you're trying to create scrollbars outside of the notebook, for controlling the contents inside a notebook frame. That's a very unusual strategy. The common approach is to create the scrollbars inside the notebook tab.

Here's an example which illustrates the concept:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

for i in range(5):
    tab = ttk.Frame(notebook)
    notebook.add(tab, text=f"Tab #{i+1}")
    text = tk.Text(tab, height=10)
    scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(tab, command=text.yview)

    scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

    text.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

    # add data to illustrate scrollability
    for line in range(20):
        text.insert("end", f"line {line+1}\n")

root.mainloop()
```

---

If you instead want a single scrollbar outside of the notebook which controls the currently visible tab, you can do that too but it requires a lot more work.

The simplest solution will be to bind to the `<<NotebookTabChanged>>` virtual event. In the bound function you can reconfigure the widgets so that the scrollbar is attached to the visible widget.

Here is a quick hack at a solution. I don't recommend this, but it illustrates that it is possible:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def reconfigure_scrollbar(event):
    index = event.widget.index("current")
    frame = event.widget.tabs()[index]
    frame_widget = root.nametowidget(frame)

    # we know the frame only has a single text widget, so
    # we know the first child is that widget. For a real
    # app you might need something smarter.
    text_widget = frame_widget.winfo_children()[0]
    text_widget.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    scrollbar.configure(command=text_widget.yview)

root = tk.Tk()
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(root)

scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
notebook.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

notebook.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", reconfigure_scrollbar)

for i in range(5):
    tab = ttk.Frame(notebook)
    notebook.add(tab, text=f"Tab #{i+1}")
    text = tk.Text(tab, height=10)
    text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

    # add data to illustrate scrollability
    for line in range(20):
        text.insert("end", f"line {line+1}\n")

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The lines indirectly causing the error are

```
global scrollbar_count
    scrollbar_count += 1

if scrollbar_count >= 2:
    text_scroll.destroy()
```

The first file created at initialization increments the `scrollbar_count` to 1.
When the second file is created, `create_scroll_bar()` inside `create_file()` is executed. This time, the `scrollbar_count` is incremented to 2. Therefore, `text_scroll.destroy()` is executed, removing the scrollbar.

However, note that this `text_scroll` is not the one created from the initialization, but the one from

```
text_scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(scroll, orient="vertical", command=textarea.yview)
```

If you need to destroy the scrollbar, You need to write the function to **destroy not the `text_scroll` just created for the second file, but the `text_scroll` that was created in the initialization.**

Comment: That explains it really well. Can't say that I know how to do that, but at least I understand the actual problem. This was very helpful. Thanks! :)